# Refer to hidden global from TypeScript module extension

Tags: module, typescript

I want to extend an existing module `Base` that declares a variable called `Math`. I also want to use the standard JS `Math` object inside the extension of the module. Is this possible?

```
module Base {
   export var Math: number;
}

// Extend module:
module Base {
   function f () {
      var y = Math.PI // how to refer to JS Math object here?
   }
}
```

(Please assume that the fragment of `Base` that defines `Math` is a third-party library, so I cannot rename `Math` to something that doesn't clash.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just store it in a variable :

```
module Base {
   export var Math: number;
}

// Extend module:
var TheMath = Math; // Create a variable 
module Base {
   function f () {
      var y = TheMath.PI // now use it 
   }
}
```

Comment: Of course. I'd forgotten that TypeScript modules are first-class :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can't.
By declaring a Math variable on your module (You are using the same module), you overriding the original JS Math object with your own.

I would rename it to MyMath or some other meaningful name, using "Math" name might get other developer confused with the original JS Math...

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately `Base` is a third-party library and it already has the variable called `Math` in it. Clarified my question accordingly.

So, I think this means that I can't _extend_ `Base`, but must import it instead.